# Asp.net mvc won't take the razor parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing on a school project where it has gone great so far but the problem has finally arrived.

I have this method in my homecontroller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSeatsInShow(int showId)
    {
        ...
        return View(realSeatList);
    }
```

In my view I use razor to parse a parameter to the controller and the controller should return the result in an address like this:

```
http://localhost:1499/Home/GetSeatsInShow/236
```

That is what it does if I do it on my other controller method called Shows on the following URL:

```
http://localhost:1499/Home/Shows/1
```

But on the GetSeatsInShow method will I need to place ?showId= like to snippet right under:

```
http://localhost:1499/Home/GetSeatsInShow/?showId=236
```

My razor ActionLink looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Vælg", "GetSeatsInShow", new { id = item.Id })
```

Can't seem to find the problem aftersome the Show method works fine with the same results as the one that doesn't work.

Comment: your `Show` method has parameter called `id`, `Show(int id)`, but your `GetSeatsInShow(int showId)` takes `showId`. Just change `new { id = item.Id }` to `new { showId = item.Id }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

You're currently passing the parameter as id, not showId, whereas your controller expects a parameter named showId.  As a result, by updating your anonymous type you can pass the correct parameter name.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Vælg", "GetSeatsInShow", new {  showId = item.Id })
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass "id" in your querystring and allow the default MVC binding to work it's magic if you update your controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Vælg", "GetSeatsInShow", new { id = item.Id })

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSeatsInShow(int id)
{
    ...
    return View(realSeatList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Vælg", "GetSeatsInShow", new { id = item.Id, showId = item.Id })
```

Answer (score 0):

you are taking an input of `showId` in `GetSeatsInShow` and in the razor you are passing in `id`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSeatsInShow(int id)
{
    ...
    return View(realSeatList);
}
```